# Real hardware or virtualized hardware for performance benchmarks of realistic web servers

Tags: sql, performance, haskell, webserver, n-tier-architecture

I am interested in performing realistic web server performance tests. As realistic I define a typical scenario of today's medium to large web sites that serve dynamic content which is often based on data stored in relational databases. Think of a large e-commerce site, a large web forum, etc., where performance problems arise.

Not of interest are websites like blogs with low traffic, or any aspect of web servers that concerns the performance of serving static content. Further, I exclude from this scenario very large websites that use a highly distributed approach like faceobook, google, amazon, reddit, etc. use., or any website that uses nosql data bases.

The question is, in the above defined 'realistic scenario', are web server (e.g., apache, programming logic, relational database, etc.) run on real hardware or on virtualized hardware? With virtualized I mean something like "Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM)" or similar would be involved.

The reason why I think about this is that often web performance tests are done in my subjective eyes poorly. For example all performance test are run on a relational db table with 12 rows and 2 columns, e.g., see: [Web Framework Benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/) as well as related discussions on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3wb0zx/what_happened_to_haskell_on_the_web_framework/).

I want to look into performing more realistic web server benchmarks in a setting with the aforementioned realistic scenario.

(Just why I think about that: In my work we don't have any virtualization on our web server hardware. We have servers with over 100gb ram and more than 100 cores. Virtualization in our setting means a dramatic penalty in performance.)

The question is, should I run the perform my performance analysis on:

- real hardware (non-virtualized, as much 'bare metal' as possible)
- virtualized hardware
- on both

From my subjective work experience I would say performance tests on real (non-virtualized) hardware are enough. Testing on both would mean more effort so I would avoid it unless a necessity.

(With my performance analysis I would later be interested to test haskell based web frameworks.)

Comment: What does this have to do with the Haskell programming language?

Comment: @dfeuer ideally one would like a fair performance benchmark for haskell based web frameworks and how they compare to other setups, see discussion, links and presented misinformation in: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3wb0zx/what_happened_to_haskell_on_the_web_framework/

Comment: As a note: virtualized hardware usually has somehow different disk I/O and network I/O performance. CPU-wise, you can probably run on 'real' or 'virtual' hardware without much difference, as long as no other VM or the host is loading the physical CPU. Unless you decide what part network and disk play in your test, it's hard to tell anything. Do you have a database, for instance? Haskell does not have any particular execution penalties, like interpretation; it does have GC pauses, though, not unlike most everything else.

Comment: @9000 thanks for your excellent points. network I/O performance is not really important for the setup, everything is not Network I/O bound. Disk is quite important for the relational db.

Comment: On real hardware I could see strange effects where twice the cores, switching from ~60 to ~120 cores reduced(!!) the web server performance by half. It was a strange effect related that correlated with interrupts. Perhaps in that corner cases CPU 'real' versus 'virtual' can make a difference.

Comment: @9000 any pointers on what is the more common scenario – 'real' vs. 'virtual' hardware – for large, but not extremly large (n-tier) web servers?

Comment: I would suggest to test your system in the environment that most of your customers have. For example if you assume that most of your customers sit in AWS or other clouds then do test your system on AWS/EC2 virtual instances. As the icing on the cake you will get the distribution of performance of your system across different types of EC2 instances which helps your user to pick the most reasonable instance type.

Comment: @DennisAnikin Thanks for your reply. The work is for scientific research considering real world medium and large websites. For this I would need some reference or statistics on how does websites are hosted on average (real vs virtual hardware).

Comment: @mrsteve You're welcome. Now I understand this clearly. These days everything goes cloud. If you're in the cloud then you're hosted virtually. Even if you're on your own premise like Google then you're also probably running on virtual servers for the sake of better operability for your fleet of machines. So I would probably bet on virtual environment. Don't have any statistics within touch though.